# Postfix + Dovecot and folder "sent mail"

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, telnet

We’re using for sending mails our own mail server Postfix + Dovecot with parameter for Postfix sender_bcc_maps which ensures that sent mail thanks to blind copy (BCC) is also sent to a sender’s address „sender+sent@email.domain“. That way is mail saved to IMAP folder with other sent e-mail messages. Because of this we don’t have to rely on mail client which could do this for us. And yet we have a problem with mails which were sent to hidden recipients (BCC).

We can’t see any information about hidden recipient in a folder with sent e-mail messages. Headers in BCC in those messages are completely missing. Reason is obvious. Mail client deletes the header when its forwarding message to a mail server and since our messages are saved into the folder by mail server it saves every mail without including BCC header.

We know that for every recipient who is included in BCC mail client in SMTP dialog shows BCC recipients as rcpt to:. If we would have 10 recipients in BCC client would send in SMTP dialog 10x rcpt to. Cause of that happening we can’t just simply identify BCC recipient on our sever and the header of BCC restore and try to ins ert it in to message in sent mail.

As we can see sending email via Google mail server keeps header BCC included and into sent mail folder its saved by Google mail server and not by mail client. How exactly is that Google doing?

Thank you, guys, for reading. I will appreciate every idea how to solve this problem and get it finally working correctly so we could apply this functionality in our environment.

Best regards.

Comment: Related: *BURL* (RFC 4468) solves this and other problems, but the other way around: MUAs upload messages once via IMAP, then instruct the SMTP submission service to load from there. Spotty client support may be a blocker for you.